# How to add custom listview to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to add a custom `listview` to one of my fragments. I have a MainActivity and 3 fragments. I am confused, should I add the `listview` XML to my `fragment` XML or `mainActivity` XML.

This is my `mainActivity.java` :

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Get the view from activity_main.xml
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Locate the viewpager in activity_main.xml
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

    // Set the ViewPagerAdapter into ViewPager
    viewPager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

    ViewPager mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPager.setPageTransformer(true, new ZoomOutPageTransformer());

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
      getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
      getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));
    }
  }

}
```

MainActivity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/mainbg">

  <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="#D3D3D3"
    android:background="#33000000"/>

  <ListView
    android:id="@+id/song_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
  </ListView>

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Comment: add listview to your fragment

Comment: Your `ListView` will be in `fragment.xml`

Comment: okay and should i add the customized list view in the same fragment.xml or in mainActivity.xml or in new layout res file @PhanVănLinh and kashyap jimuliya

Answer (score 0):

Use `ListView` in your_fragment layout file and create new layout for custom row of listview and add data of row in Custom Adapter.

ListView in fragment layout.

fragment.xml

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/song_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
```

custom_row.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sbjct"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/wlcmtxt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

CustomAdapter.java

```
public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<NoteBean> {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<NoteBean> list;

    public ListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<NoteBean> list) {
        super(context, R.layout.notice_list, list);
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        protected TextView txtSubject, txtNotice;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                        ViewGroup parent) {

        final ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            convertView = inflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.notice_list, parent, false);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            viewHolder.txtSubject = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.sbjct);
            viewHolder.txtNotice = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.wlcmtxt);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        NoteBean item = list.get(position);

        viewHolder.txtSubject.setTag(item);
        viewHolder.txtNotice.setTag(item);

        viewHolder.txtSubject.setText(item.getNewsSubject());
        viewHolder.txtNotice.setText(item.getNewsDescription());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Set Adapter to listview in fragment.

```
ListAdapter listAdapter = new ListAdapter(context, arrayList);
list.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

Comment: Sir will you please relate to this question    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38189887/how-to-add-list-of-songs-from-storage-and-display-it-on-one-of-my-fragments  with the above one and answer with what exactly i must do.

Comment: what type of error you are getting in your code. Please provide your Stack Trace or Problem.

Comment: its not the error i am facing right now. its the merging of these java classes into my fragment and main activity. how do i do it..In my commented link above i have these other java classes that i need to include to get the list in my fragment.