# How to add list of songs from storage and display it on one of my fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

How do i add list of songs inside one of my fragment java and xml and mainActivity java and xml.

This are some other java classes related to adding the songs

1- Song.java

```
public class Song {
private long id;
private String title;
private String artist;
private long duration;

public Song(long songID, String songTitle, String songArtist) {
    id=songID;
    title=songTitle;
    artist=songArtist;
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public String getArtist() {
    return artist;
}
}
```

2- MusicService.java

```
public class MusicService extends Service implements
    MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener,
    MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener {
////////////////////////////////// Declarations    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//media player
private MediaPlayer player;
//song list
private ArrayList<Song> songs;
//current position
private int songPosn;
//binder
private final IBinder musicBind = new MusicBinder();
//title of current song
private String songTitle="";
//notification id
private static final int NOTIFY_ID=1;
//shuffle flag and random
private boolean shuffle=false;
private Random rand;

public void onCreate(){
    //create the service
    super.onCreate();
    //initialize position
    songPosn=0;
    //random
    rand=new Random();
    //create player
    player = new MediaPlayer();
    //initialize
    initMusicPlayer();
}

public void initMusicPlayer(){
    //set player properties
    player.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(),
            PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
    player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    //set listeners
    player.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    player.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    player.setOnErrorListener(this);
}

//pass song list
public void setList(ArrayList<Song> theSongs){
    songs = theSongs;
}

//binder
public class MusicBinder extends Binder {
    MusicService getService() {
        return MusicService.this;
    }
}

//activity will bind to service
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return musicBind;
}

//release resources when unbind
@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent){
    player.stop();
    player.release();
    return false;
}

//////////////////////////////////////// Play a song ///////////////////////////////////////////
public void playSong(){
    //play
    player.reset();
    //get song
    Song playSong = songs.get(songPosn);
    //get title
    songTitle = playSong.getTitle();
    //get id
    long currSong = playSong.getId();
    //set uri
    Uri trackUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
            android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            currSong);
    //set the data source
    try{
        player.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), trackUri);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("MUSIC SERVICE", "Error setting data source", e);
    }
    player.prepareAsync();
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//set the song
public void setSong(int songIndex){
    songPosn=songIndex;
}

///////////////////////////Completion,Prepared,Error////////////////////////////////////////////
@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
    //check if playback has reached the end of a track
    if(player.getCurrentPosition()>0){
        mp.reset();
        playNext();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
    Log.v("MUSIC PLAYER", "Playback Error");
    mp.reset();
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    //start playback
    mp.start();
    //notification
    Intent notIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    notIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendInt = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            notIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);

    builder.setContentIntent(pendInt)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.play)
            .setTicker(songTitle)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setContentTitle("Playing")
            .setContentText(songTitle);
    Notification not = builder.build();
    startForeground(NOTIFY_ID, not);
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////playback methods///////////////////////////////////////////////
public int getPosn(){
    return player.getCurrentPosition();
}

public int getDur(){
    return player.getDuration();
}

public boolean isPng(){
    return player.isPlaying();
}

public void pausePlayer(){
    player.pause();
}

public void seek(int posn){
    player.seekTo(posn);
}

public void go(){
    player.start();
}

//skip to previous track
public void playPrev(){
    songPosn--;
    if(songPosn<0) songPosn=songs.size()-1;
    playSong();
}

//skip to next
public void playNext(){
    if(shuffle){
        int newSong = songPosn;
        while(newSong==songPosn){
            newSong=rand.nextInt(songs.size());
        }
        songPosn=newSong;
    }
    else{
        songPosn++;
        if(songPosn>=songs.size()) songPosn=0;
    }
    playSong();
}

//toggle shuffle
public void setShuffle(){
    if(shuffle) shuffle=false;
    else shuffle=true;
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    stopForeground(true);
}

}
```

3- SongAdapter.java

```
public class SongAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

//song list and layout
private ArrayList<Song> songs;
private LayoutInflater songInf;

//constructor
public SongAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Song> theSongs){
    songs = theSongs;
    songInf=LayoutInflater.from(c);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return songs.size();
}

@Override
public Song getItem(int arg0) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    //map to song layout
    LinearLayout songLay = (LinearLayout)songInf.inflate(R.layout.song, parent, false);
    //get title and artist views
    TextView songView = (TextView)songLay.findViewById(R.id.song_title);
    TextView artistView = (TextView)songLay.findViewById(R.id.song_artist);
    //get song using position
    Song currSong = songs.get(position);
    //get title and artist strings
    songView.setText(currSong.getTitle());
    artistView.setText(currSong.getArtist());
    //set position as tag
    songLay.setTag(position);
    return songLay;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have adapter so now you need to have a listview to handle the data.

- First, please include ListView widget in your layout of `Fragment`
- Second, set adapter to your `listview`

Your adapter should use `viewholder` to improve performance